# Determining convergence of multistep method

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm a bit confused on how to show that whether multi-step scheme such as 
$$u_{n+2}-3u_{n+1}+2u_n=-hf(t_n,u_n)$$

(modified from [these](http://persson.berkeley.edu/228A/Fall10/doc/lec20-2x3.pdf) lecture notes) is convergent. Neither my lecture notes nor my textbook provide any examples on how to do this. I've attempted to search online, but have come across conflicting suggestions (using the Dahlquist equivalence theorem, others say taking the Taylor expansion of the truncation error is sufficient).

Additionally, the problem I'm trying to solve involves more $f$ terms, e.g.

$$u_{n+2}-3u_{n+1}+2u_n=-hf(t_n,u_n) + 3hf(t_{n-2},u_{n-2})$$

How would I go about showing that the scheme converges?

Comment: To prove convergence, you need to prove consistency and stability. For consistency, show that truncation error is $O(h^m)$, $m\geq1$ (equivalent to showing that the coefficients of $u_{n+2}$, $u_{n+1}$, and $u_n$ sum to zero I think) (since you don't have a specific ODE you can't check that the scheme is consistent with a particular ODE). Then for stability, I don't see why you couldn't use zero-stability as defined in the lecture notes you linked to. I think your general problem is a type of delay differential equation, in which case a lot of this goes straight out the window.

Answer (score 0):

The consistency requires in the first example
$$
(1+x)^2-3(1+x)+2 -\ln(1+x)·(-1) = O(x^{p+1})
$$
with $p\ge 1$. Expansion gives
$$
1+2x+x^2-3-3x+2 + (x-x^2/2+x^3/3\mp…)=1/2·x^2+O(x^3)
$$
so is consistent of order 1. Your proposed modification has
\begin{align}
O(x^{p+1})&=(1+x)^2-3(1+x)+2 -\ln(1+x)·(-1+3(1+x)^{-2}) \\
&=(1+x)^{-2}·\left(1+4x+6x^2+4x^3+x^4-3-9x-9x^2-3x^3+2+4x+4x^2+(x-x^2/2+x^3/3\mp…)·(1+2x+x^2-3)\right)\\
&= O(x)
\end{align}
which fails the consistency test.

---

Without changing the left side the stability remains the same. Changing the right side one can increase the order inside the proposed frame of usable function values.

To get a consistent method with two steps forward on the left and two backward on the right, use
\begin{align}
β_0(1+x)^2+β_1(1+x)+β_2 
&= \frac{(1+x)^2((1+x)^2-3(1+x)^2+2}{x-x^2/2+x^3/3+O(x^4)}
\\
&=\frac{(1+2x+x^2)(-x+x^2)}{x(1-x/2+x^2/3-x^3/4+O(x^4)}
\\ \\
&=-1 - 3/2·x + 7/12·x^2 + 37/24·x^3 + O(x^4)
\\ \\
&=13/12 - 8/3·(1+x) + 7/12·(1+x)^2 + 37/24·x^3 + O(x^4).
\end{align}

Reading off the coefficients and using that $x$ stands for $x=\exp(h\frac{d}{dx})-1=h\frac{d}{dx}+O(h^2)$, this gives the order 3 consistent method with error term
$$
x_{n+2}-3x_{n+1}+2x_n=\frac{h}{12}\Bigl(7·f(t_n,x_n)-32·f(t_{n-1},x_{n-1})+13·f(t_{n-2},x_{n-2})\Bigr)\\+\frac{37}{24}·h^4 x^{(4)}(t_n)+O(h^5)
$$
Or without the term at index $n-1$ the order 2 method 
$$
x_{n+2}-3x_{n+1}+2x_n=-\frac{h}{4}·\Bigl(3·f(t_n,x_n)+f(t_{n-2},x_{n-2})\Bigr)+\frac{4}{3}·h^3 x^{(3)}(t_{n}-\tfrac{43}{32}h)+O(h^5)
$$